# Is it possible to create a new column for each iteration in XlsxWriter

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I want to write data into Excel columns using XlsxWriter. One 'set' of data gets written for each iteration. Each set should be written in a separate column. How do I do this?
I have tried playing around with the `col` value as follows:

- At `[1]` I define `i=0` outside the loop and later increment it by `1` and set `col=i`. When this is done output is blank. To me this is the most logical solution & I don't know why it won't work.
- At `[2]` `i` is defined inside the loop. When this happens one column gets written.
- At `[3]` I define `col` the standard way. This works as expected: One column gets written.

My code:

```
import xlsxwriter

txt_file = open('folder/txt_file','r')
lines = dofile.readlines()

# [1]Define i outside the loop. When this is used output is blank.
i = 0
for line in lines:

    if condition_a is met:
        #parse text file to find a string. reg_name = string_1.

    elif condition_b:
        #parse text file for a second string. esto_name = string_2.

    elif condition_c:
        #parse text file for a group of strings. 
        # use .split() to append these strings to a list.
        # reg_vars = list of strings.

        #[2] Define i inside the loop. When this is used one column gets written. Relevant for [1] & [2].
        i+=1 #Increment for each loop
        row=1
        col=i #Increments by one for each iteration, changing the column.


        #[3] #Define col =1. When this is used one column also gets written.
        col=1 

        #Open Excel
        book= xlsxwriter.Workbook('folder/variable_list.xlsx')
        sheet = book.add_worksheet()

        #Write reg_name
        sheet.write(row, col, reg_name)
        row+=1

         #Write esto_name
        sheet.write(row, col, esto_name)
        row+=1
        #Write variables
        for variable in reg_vars:
            row+=1
            sheet.write(row, col, variable)   

    book.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XlsxWriter [write_column()](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-column) method to write a list of data as a column.

However, in this particular case the issue seems to be that you are creating a new, duplicate, file via `xlsxwriter.Workbook()` each time you go through the `condition_c` part of the loop. Therefore the last value of `col` is used and the entire file is overwritten the next time through the loop.

You should probably move the creation of the xlsx file outside the loop. Probably to the same place you `open()` the text file.

Comment: hmm, not sure that solves the iteration through columns though?